# fasttext works in ubuntu terminal but not in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, fasttext

Execution from ubuntu terminal -->

b@PC:~/fastText$ ./fasttext supervised -input /traningText.txt -output model_trained -label  **label**
Read 2M words
Number of words:  78155
Number of labels: 116
Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:  296977 lr:  0.000000 loss:  1.616176 ETA:   0h 0m

Execution from jupyter notebook -->
Attempt 1 (after switching to fastText folder)

./fasttext supervised -input traningText.txt -output model_trained -label **label**

gives the error -

File "", line 1
    ./fasttext supervised -input traningText.txt -output model_trained -label **label**
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Attempt 2 (after switching to fastText folder)

fasttext supervised -input trainingText -output model_trained -label  **label**

gives the error -

File "", line 1
    fasttext supervised -input trainingText.txt -output model_trained -label  **label**
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Attempt 3 (after switching to fastText folder)

/home/fastText/fasttext supervised -input trainingText.txt -output model_trained -label **label**

gives the error -

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 home/fastText/fasttext(supervised, -input, trainingText.txt, -output, model_trained, -label, **label**)

NameError: name 'home' is not defined

What is going wrong ?  How can I get my fasttext command to execute from Jupyter notebook ? Pls advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute shell commands from Jupyter and expect the right output.

If you want to use FastText from Jupyter, my advice is to install [FastText python binding](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python).

You can read [official fastText tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html) (now explaining python binding, too).

[Here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python/doc/examples) you find some examples.